# LDAP over TLS with ldap-client in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ldap

I am fairly new to the concept of domains and am trying to implement LDAP over TLS in node. And I have been stuck with this issue for many days now. I am using [ldap-client](https://github.com/jeremycx/node-LDAP).

```
var LDAP = require('ldap-client');

var ldap = new LDAP({
    validatecert:    false,             // Verify server certificate
    ...
}, function(err) {
    // connected and ready    
});
```

so with some research I came into conclusion that, if the field **validatecert** is to be set amount these values

```
LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER  = 0;
LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD   = 1;
LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND = 2; 
LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW  = 3;
LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_TRY    = 4;
```

which was quoted under the section `TLS` in the library documentation

> TLS can be used via the ldaps:// protocol string in the URI attribute on instantiation. If you want to eschew server certificate checking (if you have a self-signed cserver certificate, for example), you can set the verifycert attribute to LDAP.LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER, or one of the following values:

With which I could setup a secure connection.

I know that we need certificates for TLS connection to work. One is held by the server and another by the client (me).
My question is if I set the field to any of the said methods:

- How am I to verify that my connection is secure ?
- Where do I see the certificates or not see them at all ?
- Do I have to manually generate certificates from the server and use them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Certificates are a means to help others verify that the entity presenting the certificate is indeed who it is claiming to be. Thus, when you connect to a server and server returns a certificate, then through that certificate you can be sure that server is indeed the server and not an imposter.*

*The power of certificate is due to the issuer (also called Certificate Authority or CA). If you trust the issuer, then you effectively trust the certificates issued by it. A list of prominent CAs is usually present in the OS itself, so getting a certificate and verification of that certificate is transparent to the application developer, especially when you are using libraries.*

---

Taking your points one by one:

> I know that we need certificates for TLS connection to work. One is held by the server and another by the client (me).

You didn't ask any question here, here is some general info. Usually server verification is all that's needed. In high security environments, client verification is done too and there you (i.e. the client) would need a certificate from a CA to verify yourself to the server. But, in most applications, server verification is sufficient.

It is similar to Normal Forms in RDBMS normalization. Even though you have Normal Forms as strict as 6NF, usually RDBMS's are normalized till 3NF.

---

> How am I to verify that my connection is secure?

Generally, if you are using a well known library, (like curl or openLDAP) calling its secure connection methods is enough. It is very very unlikely that you called a function that the library claims to be secure but it turns out to be a farce.

To be sure though, you can look at your traffic with the server. Wireshark is often used for network traffic analysis.

---

> Where do I see the certificates or not see them at all?

In most cases you don't see the certificates. All you do is tell your library how strict you want the verification to be. And then your library will take care of the rest - often throwing an exception or logging an error if there is some issue with the certificate.

If you are using a client certificate then you would have to keep it on the file system and point your library to it. It is generally a .pem file.

---

> Do I have to manually generate certificates from the server and use them?

No. For server certs, it is the responsibility of the server to provide you with a valid cert. All you have to do is just check that the certificate sent by server is from an established CA - which, as told earlier, is generally a transparent step for the developer using the library.

In cases where you do not care much or in situations where you want to start coding and CA is yet to issue a certificate for you, you can program the server to provide its clients with a self-signed certificate and program the clients to keep the verification less strict.

A self-signed certificate has little value in terms of security. It is like server saying - 'Hey, I'm telling you that I'm the guy you want to talk to.' That clearly isn't enough. You want a third person (i.e. the CA), whom you fully trust, to confirm that that is the guy you wanted to talk to.

Comment: This was an old question. I don't even remember what I did to fix it. But as far as I can remember, I think I used a self-signed certificate. But this answer is very detailed. I will select it as the correct answer in case others face the same problem I did. Thank you for taking the time to answer all the queries.

Comment: @Prasanna: I know this is an old one. I gave the answer to record my learning. Have been struggling with these and other related questions myself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions asked.

Comment: @reinierpost: Which one did I leave unanswered?

Comment: @displayName: Sorry, my bad, you did answer them. I was looking for concrete examples of how to do things, but the question doesn't request them.

Comment: @reinierpost: Ah! ok. BTW, I was doing this work very recently. If you ask a question about it, please tag me in a comment on that question. I'll try to answer.